# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 - Tasks Generate Script - Missing database

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, task

I am trying to generate a script to create all tables/stored procedures/etc. for a database using:

SQL Server Management Studio 2008 -> Right Click on the Database Name -> **Tasks -> Generate Scripts**

But the database name does not show up on the list (the rest of the databases shows up).

The other databases has same permissions and I'm using the same user account for them.

I tried to google for a reason why the database name is not showing up but haven't been successful in finding that out yet.

Anybody knows why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options, you can change Script Create to true[image].